# Creating a build system of classnames

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

My question is based on this question: https://www.quora.com/How-do-Facebook-structure-their-CSS-class-names

Facebook & Google uses some sort of build system to convert class names (understood semantically by a developer) to short names which are easy on bandwidth thus creating a compressed code.

So, how do we create this build system? If it is just changing the classnames on PHP side, its a different thing. But, the same classes have to be changed on CSS and Javascript sides. So, how do we keep everything intact when doing this?

Classes like "._4q7-" and "._4q82" are insane to work with if there is no build system.

I am using PHP,MySQL,JQuery...

Comment: [Less](http://lesscss.org/) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) ?

Comment: Less and Sass are CSS preprocessors.. I dont think they have any impact on your HTML or JS codes...

Comment: I think the confusion is happening because the question may be somewhat unclear. The OP is asking what do the above mentioned sites use for their builders or how do to make a builder to generate the obscure class names which reference back to the correct `css` `class`.

Comment: @Script47: sorry if I am not clear.. I wanted to implement something similar on my site. And at the same time keep my CSS & JS intact.

Comment: @vignesh I understood what you meant however the answer which was provided and the first comment suggests that others are not understanding what you mean. You should probably update the OP to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Gulp, this seems to be on the right path:

https://github.com/calebthebrewer/gulp-selectors

Takes care of selector consistency between CSS, JS & HTML. Also provides the ability to process custom files, so it could maybe be used with other kinds of views, not exclusively plain HTML files.

```
var processors = {
    'css':  ['scss', 'css'],        // run the css processor on .scss and .css files
    'html': ['haml'],               // run the html processor on .haml files
    'js-strings':   ['js']          // run the js-strings plugin on js files
},
ignores = {
    classes: ['hidden', 'active']   // ignore these class selectors,
    ids: '*'                        // ignore all IDs
};

gs.run(processors, ignores);
```

Comment: Thank you. But one question. The code written is in JS. So, does this mean it is converted to short names only after coming to the client side? Cause it does not improve performance that way.

Comment: Yes, it's written in JS because Gulp (Gulp.js) runs locally on Node.js, but once you've run the build process locally, you can upload the resulting files to be served from the server.

Comment: seems like a big task.. write the code->build it->get rendered result->render the new result to users... too much.. ty anyways.

Comment: I'm not sure you're thinking about it correctly. Gulp and the whole build process is happening locally, but we're uploading the resulting files to our website, this way we can work locally on the unminified / unrewritten selectors / scss files. This way the website users are getting the final processed files, be it minfied styles and scripts, rewritten selectors, etc. 
I recommend you have a look at Gulp and try setup a basic build for SCSS compiling or JS minification, once you have that working I'm pretty sure it will shed some light on the selector rewriting problem.

Comment: sure.. will try.. thanx